# How to write numbers to a text file (line by line) and add all of them?

Tags: python

I'm making a stock game's python version. There are stock prices and users can buy them. I need to make a thing that shows the average price of purchases made by the user when buying more than 0 stocks. Stock prices are connected to a randomizer. That's the story. But I think I can make a smaller code and then place that code into that game's code. Here's that small code:

```
numA=int(input("Number 1: "))
numB=int(input("Number 2: "))

with open('average.txt','a') as avg:
  avg.write(str(numA))
  avg.write("\n")
  avg.write(str(numB))
  avg.write("\n")
```

How can I make a code that reads the text file and sums `numA` and `numB` without doing something like `total=numA+numB`. I want the program to import it from the text file because as I said, I'm making a bigger program that includes loops and I will use the text file as memory.

Comment: save your total in your text file as well

Comment: Small hint: `avg.write(str(numA))` followed by `avg.write("\n")` could be written as `avg.write(f'{numA}\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
with open("New Text Document.txt", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()
    
    nums = text.replace("\n", " ").split(" ")
    nums = (int(i) for i in nums if i.isdigit())
    
    total = sum(nums)
```

I basically read the file in read mode and stored it inside of the `text` variable. Then I **replaced** all the **newlines** with **spaces** and then **split** the string by **spaces**. Then I used a **generator comprehension** to check if the element I is a number and if it is, I added it to the `nums` generator. And finally I used **sum** to get the sum of the numbers inside of the `nums` generator.

Or you could do something like this:

```
with open("file", "r") as file:
    try:
        total = sum(map(int, file))
    except ValueError:
        print("File has to contain only numbers.")
```

Comment: You can replace the first two lines in the `with` block with `nums = list(file)`. And if you omit the check for digits (because something will be wrong if the file contains other stuff) the full content of the `with` block could be `total = sum(map(int, list(file)))`.

Comment: I still had too much code (that was an `OutOfCoffeeError`). `list` is not needed here because `map` will work on any iterable. So it boils down to `total = sum(map(int, file))`

Comment: Nice edit, but you won't get a `SyntaxError` if the conversion fails. It will be a `ValueError` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one :

```
import numpy as np   
with open('average.txt','r') as avg:
    lines = avg.readlines()
    Sum = np.sum([int(line.rstrip()) for line in lines], axis = 0)
```

Comment: `numpy` for something that you can do with simple built-in functions in Python?

Comment: @Matthias maybe he/she wants to increase performance (I'm guessing numpy sum is faster than normal sum), but even if that's the case importing the whole numpy module just for this simple calculation doesn't make so much sense in my opinion (maybe do from numpy import sum as np_sum).

Comment: `sum` in Python is pretty fast. And this solution is even slowed down by the unnecessary call to `rstrip`.

Comment: Hi, because he wants to deal with bid data ( stock game) this code will perform much better

Comment: I used `timeit` to measure the performance of the full script with 10000 numbers in the file and 1000 repetitions. Result: your numpy version takes double the time than the simple approach with `total = sum(map(int, list(file)))`. I tested it again with 100.000 numbers and the numpy version still needs double the time. Don't assume that something is faster just because "numpy" is written on it. That's cargo cult programming.

Comment: Your code will be faster if you drop `rstrip`. And it will be even faster if you replace the list creation in the first parameter of `np.sum` with a generator: `np.sum((int(line) for line in lines), axis=0)`. But it's still slower than the approach without numpy.